# Where is the macro INT_MAX defined?

Tags: c++, c, macros, c-preprocessor

When I was doing reverse engineering, I came across the macro `INT_MAX`, but was unable to find its value. So how does the preprocessor knows its value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `#include <limits.h>` (or `<climits>` in C++) then `INT_MAX` is guaranteed to be defined.

Whether or not it actually *appears* in that file is another question - it's possible that the compiler hardcodes it (unlikely in my judgement) or it's in a different file that's reached by the ones I've given above.

Comment: #define INT_MAX   __ INT_MAX __ is present in the limits.h file but there was no __INT_MAX__ definition found anywhere. Any views on it?

Comment: @ShaikTanveerUlhuq: `__INT_MAX__` might be in the compiler itself.

Comment: thanks @Bathsheba , I got it from `gcc -dM -E  - < /dev/null | grep __INT_MAX__`